# .net - access files among different projects in a solution

Tags: .net, resources, projects-and-solutions, share

I have multiple .net projects under a solution.

Specifically, i have few content files like pdf's, word docs under an asp.net project that i would like to access from a windows application project.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding the file as an Existing file and then specify that it is a linked file when selecting that file. After that you can flip the option to always copy to the output folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a single "resources" project, and share it between your ASP.NET project and your Windows Application project.

You'd then just load the resources from the third, shared project as needed.

Comment: how to access the shared resource files?